# How do I copy data from Command Prompt in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, copy-paste

I'm running some tests that take some time in Command Prompt. When you type <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> Command Prompt on Windows 7, it appears as `^C` (or while the program is running it pauses the program and kills the tests).

How can I copy it in a more efficient manner than just typing it all into notepad and then copying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `MARK`

So, right click in the console window, and choose mark (first in the list). Highlight the area you want to copy using the mouse. Press return on your keyboard. That has now copied to your clipboard and you can paste it.

Alternatively, instead of `MARK` choose `Select All`, and then press enter for the same result.

Comment: Oh, `mark` there.

Comment: It's not the easiest but I think CTRL+C will actually cancel some operations so becareful with that shortcut

Comment: Yeah, that also throws some stuff off.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to enter

yourcommand > c:\temp\cmd.txt

Your output will be copied into a cmd.txt file